# How to achieve higher display resolution for Ubuntu under VirtualBox?

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, display-settings

In this setup, Ubuntu under VM only achieves low resolution at 640 * 480 while host is 1920 * 1024.

How to, (I believe is to configure X server), achieve higher resolution?

I have set in VirtualBox 3D acceleration ON.

VirtualBox installed with all default setting.

Ubuntu 14.04 Desktop installed as the only VM.

Intel i5, 2.8GHz, 4 cores, 4G RAM, Windows 7.

Comment: 1920 * 1024?! Perhaps 1920 * 1080 or 1920 * 1200.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to [install the guest additions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22743/how-do-i-install-guest-additions-in-a-virtualbox-vm). You may need to install the addons that come with VirtualBox (insert the virtual CD) rather than the ones in the Ubuntu package as the Ubutu package might not support your VirtualBox version.

I think you'll need to log out and back in after installing the guest additions. After that, you can resize the VirtualBox window, and the guest resolution will adjust.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use “Additional Driver” in `System → Administration → Additional Driver.

Ubuntu will find the correct driver for the VM.